# Ruby on Rails Variables not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using [bitcoin-ruby](https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby) and I want to generate an address and display it when requested.

[Here is the code I have currently](https://gist.github.com/nahtnam/e4bd0ea5c0d25dd9384e):

```
resource :btc do
  key = Bitcoin::generate_key
  address = Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(key[1])
  public_key = key[1]
  private_key = key[0]
  get :address do
    { :address => address, :public_key => public_key, :private_key => private_key }
  end
end
```

The syntax and everything is correct, ***but*** there is one issue.

If you request the page you get an address, then if you refresh the page, you get the exact same address. I want it to generate a random address ***every time*** the page is requested. I'm not sure how to go about this.

I tried placing the variables outside of the resource tags but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I move the variables inside the `get :address do` scope.

Comment: can you explain how you were able to get this working? I'm not understanding from your above post.

I am trying to do the exact same thing as outlined in my SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031323/bitcoin-ruby-gem-generating-same-address-every-time?noredirect=1#comment37045227_24031323

I would like to use a method that will return a different address each time I run it seeded by a provided bitcoin address.