# Bitcoin-ruby gem generating same address every time?

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

I am trying to use the `bitcoin-ruby` gem to create a new address for payment transactions from my public Bitcoin Address.

I am able to use the `pubkey_to_address` method to do this. However, each time I run the method the resulting address, `payment_address`, is the same. Services such as blockchain.info return a different address each time which is more consistent with my requirement.

### Bitcoin-ruby github reference

https://github.com/lian/bitcoin-ruby/blob/master/lib/bitcoin.rb#L128

### My Code is below

```
require 'bitcoin'

ORIGIN_ADDRESS = "1BjxMfaBpsXu8AnAA44TTgopWuE6QamvCQ"
payment_address = Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(ORIGIN_ADDRESS)
puts payment_address
# => "171GYkox1rWqNf8skyK2Aw9EAnVJ1wPwKf"
```

Comment: These services give you different addresses for the same public key? Really?

Comment: Yes every time. It was my understanding that this is the expected behavior when creating an address to be used for requesting Bitcoin. Blockchain.info and Coinbase do this via both API and web console when generating address for a merchant transactions. 

I found detailed information detailing generating of new address here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses

Comment: It just occurred to me that this might be due to bitcoin address forwarding feature that these services are offering. I'm guessing that they store the provided Bitcoin address, generate a new pub/priv key and address... when the item is paid it forwards to the original provided Bitcoin address. Does this sound crazy? I'm learning about these details still. Reading through the above wiki details, I don't see any operation that would introduce randomness into it.

Comment: Yes, usually, you generate a new keypair (and address) for every transaction. The wallet hides this multitude from you, but behind the scenes, your wallet contains a lot of keys.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now. Thanks for your response Thilo. As soon as you said "Really?" I stared questioning my assumptions and it all started to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

With @Thilo's feedback I now understand this. The services that I had been using were abstracting the fact that the were generating new "receiver" address with new private key that automatically forwards back to the Bitcoin address I provided them when a transaction was confirmed on block chain.

As Thilo points out, I should use new pub/priv key for each transaction and keep the priv key offline if at all possible. This priv key can then be used for future Bitcoin transactions against funds paid to the public address.

I'm getting there.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to what you had. Try doing this:

```
 def gen_address
   ORIGIN_ADDRESS = "1BjxMfaBpsXu8AnAA44TTgopWuE6QamvCQ"
   return Bitcoin::pubkey_to_address(ORIGIN_ADDRESS)
 end
 puts gen_address()
```

(There might be a syntax error, but the code should be something like this).

Let me know if this doesnt work.